Missing context menu in Windows
I am trying to get access to context menu of file in Windows 11 using following code:
#include <windows.h>
#include <commctrl.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <shtypes.h>
#include <shobjidl_core.h>
#include <shlobj_core.h>
#include <algorithm>

bool openShellContextMenuForObject(const std::wstring& path, int xPos, int yPos, void* parentWindow)
{
    ITEMIDLIST* id = 0;
    std::wstring windowsPath = path;
    std::replace(windowsPath.begin(), windowsPath.end(), '/', '\\');
    HRESULT result = SHParseDisplayName(windowsPath.c_str(), 0, &id, 0, 0);
    if (!SUCCEEDED(result) || !id)
        return false;
    //CItemIdListReleaser idReleaser(id);

    IShellFolder* ifolder = 0;

    LPCITEMIDLIST idChild = 0;
    result = SHBindToParent(id, IID_IShellFolder, (void**)&ifolder, &idChild);
    if (!SUCCEEDED(result) || !ifolder)
        return false;
    //CComInterfaceReleaser ifolderReleaser(ifolder);

    IContextMenu* imenu = 0;
    result = ifolder->GetUIObjectOf((HWND)parentWindow, 1, (const ITEMIDLIST**)&idChild, IID_IContextMenu, 0, (void**)&imenu);
    if (!SUCCEEDED(result) || !ifolder)
        return false;
    //CComInterfaceReleaser menuReleaser(imenu);

    HMENU hMenu = CreatePopupMenu();
    if (!hMenu)
        return false;

    if (SUCCEEDED(imenu->QueryContextMenu(hMenu, 0, 1, 0x7FFF, CMF_NORMAL)))
    {
        int iCmd = TrackPopupMenuEx(hMenu, TPM_RETURNCMD, xPos, yPos, (HWND)parentWindow, NULL);

        if (iCmd > 0)
        {
            CMINVOKECOMMANDINFOEX info = { 0 };
            info.cbSize = sizeof(info);
            info.fMask = CMIC_MASK_UNICODE;
            info.hwnd = (HWND)parentWindow;
            info.lpVerb = MAKEINTRESOURCEA(iCmd - 1);
            info.lpVerbW = MAKEINTRESOURCEW(iCmd - 1);
            info.nShow = SW_SHOWNORMAL;
            imenu->InvokeCommand((LPCMINVOKECOMMANDINFO)&info);
        }
    }
    DestroyMenu(hMenu);

    return true;
}


int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE, PWSTR, int nShowCmd) {
    const char CLASS_NAME[] = "SampleWindowClass";

    WNDCLASSA wc = {};
    wc.lpfnWndProc = DefWindowProc;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.lpszClassName = CLASS_NAME;

    RegisterClassA(&wc);

    HWND hwnd = CreateWindowExA(
        0, CLASS_NAME, "Window", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL
    );

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nShowCmd);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    openShellContextMenuForObject(L"C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\file.txt", 100, 100, hwnd);

    MSG msg = {};
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return 0;
}

Everything is OK except that the "Give access to" menu submenus missing.

Any other submenus works fine and shows submenus correct but only submenus of "Give access to" does not shown. It shows empty submenu. How can i fix that?

I don't know about this one specifically, but historically many of the context menu extensions that provided submenus required you to handle various messages in your window procedure and pass them to IContextMenu2::HandleMenuMsg.
